# Preventing every push notification being executed iOS titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, titanium, titanium-alloy

If I get multiple push notifications whilst app is in foreground. The callback method will execute every push notification one by one.

```
        callback : function(e) {

            if (e.inBackground == 1) {

//came from background - do something.


            } else {

            //  Titanium.UI.iPhone.setAppBadge(null);

                //check type, if it is chat.
                if (type == 'chat') {


                    //check if window is already opened or not, if so fire event handler

                    if (currentWindow == '_chatWindow') {


                        //update view directly after entering app from the background. Fire event handler
                        Ti.App.fireEvent('_updateChat', {});

                    } else if (currentWindow == '_messages') {
                        //refresh messages screen if on messages screen and chat message arrives

                        //update view directly after entering app from the background. Fire event handler
                        Ti.App.fireEvent('_updateMessages', {});

                    } else {

                        //display local notification

                    }

                }
```

If the push notification has come from the background it is easy to deal with, as the push notification that is activated is the one the user chooses to swipe. However, if multiple push notifications come into the foreground and say it's chat, it will execute them multiple times.

How can I handle push notifications in the foreground better? Thanks

Update:

tried this code without much luck

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('_displayNotification', function(e) {

    //store all push notifications in array
    var pushArray = [];
    var countPushNotifications;

    //currentTime to cross reference
    var currentTime = new Date();

    if (currentTime - Alloy.Globals.pushTime < 3000) {
        //do something
        pushArray.add(e.PushNotificationData);
    } else {
        //after 3 seconds remove event handler
        //fire event to filter array and process notification, reset time for next event
        Alloy.Globals.pushTime = null;
        Ti.App.removeEventListener('_displayNotification', {});

    }
    //first push notification, will be the current time
    if(Alloy.Globals.pushTime==null){
    Alloy.Globals.pushTime = currentTime;
    }


});
```

Trying to get all the push notifications inside the array, for further filtering.

Update 2:

```
if (Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag == 1) {

                            Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag = null;

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                Ti.App.fireEvent('_displayNotification', {
                                    PushMessage : message
                                });
                            }, 6000);

                        } else {

                            Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag = 1;

                            Ti.App.fireEvent('_displayNotification', {
                                PushMessage : message
                            });

                        }
```

I have tried to execute push notifications alternatively.

1st notification - fires instantly.
2nd notification - fires after 6 seconds.
3rd notification - instantly.
4th notification - fires after 6 seconds.

and so on...

however the code only works for

notification 1 and 2.

Fails when it hits the 3rd notification.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  What do you mean by "better"?  What is the desired behaviour and what about your current approach doesn't meet this?

Comment: If you have multiple push notifications received at once, say 5 messages, and you receive them in the foreground. At the time of receiving them, let's say that you are in the Chat window as described in the code above. By default EACH push notification will execute one after the other, creating a duplicate action. When in that scenario, it would be smarter if I only execute the push notification I want. In that case the last one.

Comment: But that isn't how it works - your event handler will receive the events sequentially. You need to determine if the action is required or not - perhaps store the time stamp of the previous action and determine if this event needs to be processed or not.  You don't say why having multiple event triggers is a problem

Comment: If I am in the chat window for example, chatting to someone. It will mean duplicate api calls to update the chat window. When it just makes more sense to update it with the last push notification that is related to chat.

Comment: Ok, so you are worried about the extra api calls on the cloud platform?  If so, then the only solution I can see is to keep a time stamp and discard extra notifications that arrive within a certain time window of the previous

Comment: Tried the time stamp solution without much luck, updated my question with the code. Could you have a look and let me know and help - Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if Push is received in foreground or background using inBackground Property of push here is the **[documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/PushNotificationData-property-inBackground)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works fine, however the problem is that  
if you have multiple push notifications received at once, say 5 messages, and you receive them in the foreground. At the time of receiving them, let's say that you are in the Chat window as described in the code above. By default EACH push notification will execute one after the other, creating a duplicate action. When in that scenario, it would be smarter if I only execute the push notification I want. In that case the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the Titanium experience to give you actual code, but this is the approach you need to take:

1. When you receive a notification, check to see if a (global) boolean `receivedNotification` is false
2. If it is false, set it to true, store the event into a global and schedule a [`setTimeout`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global-method-setTimeout) function for, say, 3 seconds, to process the event and reset `receivedNotification` to false
3. If `receivedNotification` is true, update the global event to the newer notification

In the process event method that is triggered via the timer your will do what you currently do in the first section of code.

This will ensure that the event is processed no longer than 3 seconds after it is received and that events will be processed, at most, once every three seconds.

Your code looks pretty close, except you are trying to fire the first event immediately and then subsequent events after a delay.  Unfortunately I don't believe that this is possible, because you have no way of seeing if there are events queued immediately.  I think that you are always going to have to incur the delay, but you can tune the delay to find a balance between responsiveness and reduced API calls -

```
if (Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag == null) {

    Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag = 1;

    Alloy.Globals.messageToPush=message;

    setTimeout(function() {
          Alloy.Globals.countPushNotificationsFlag = null;
          Ti.App.fireEvent('_displayNotification', {
            PushMessage : Alloy.Globals.messageToPush
          });
    }, 3000);

 }
 else {
     Alloy.Globals.messageToPush=message;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried a similar route, it half works - see original answer. Cheers.